# Laravel orchid make polymorphing relation

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-9, orchid

I have polymorphic relations

```php
class ActionItems extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    use AsSource;
    use Filterable;

    public function actionable(){
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

And

```php
public function actionable(){
    return $this->morphOne(Action::class,'actionable');
}
```

How I make form for polymorphing relations?

I find this code:

```php
Relation::morphMap([
    'image' => Image::class,
    'post' => Post::class,
]);
```

https://laravel-news.com/enforcing-morph-maps-in-laravel

and is not work.

Comment: *"is not work"* - That is not a useful statement at all... Now working how? What is happening with this code vs what are you expecting? Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76433241/edit) to include more helpful information.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.